# Extending binomial identity $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}=0$ to $0<x<1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, analytic-continuation

I found in Matlab that 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n~\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}=0$$
for $x$ integer with $1\leq x< n$ only (I am about 95% sure of this since the sum is numerically unstable and cannot give accurate results for $n>\approx 20$)

Is there a way of obtaining a similar result for real $0<x<1$? Is analytic continuation useful?

If it is useful, for $x=0$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n~\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}=-2\sum_{k=0}^n~\frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: The sum shouldn't be $0$ when $x$ is not an integer, even if $ 1 \leq x < n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mathematica and/or Wolfram Alpha, 
I get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n~\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}=\frac{(x-1)! (n-x)!}{x (x+1) (-x-2)! (n+x)!}.
$$
However, the intermediate steps are unavailable.

I guess one can obtain the same identity with [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm).
One can find a comprehensive introduction of Gosper's algorithm in the book [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).

Comment: Thanks I double checked that it is correct for several values of $n$ and $x$ (with $x<1$). Shouldn't you use gamma functions as $x$ is non-integer? It also gives zero for $1\leq x<n$.

Comment: With the definition $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$, you can use both notations interchangeably.

Comment: Alright then should be fine